# Split at every new instance of string Python

Tags: python

I am trying to split some file metadata taken from dropbox at every instance of 'FileMetadata' and write to a text file. It's printing in my console as I need but appending to the text file the new line isn't coming through.

To provide some context to the code I am getting the file meta data and writing it to a file and reading it to then split it.

```
with open (write_file, 'rt') as read_file:
    contents = read_file.read()
    data = contents.split('FileMetadata')
    print (data)

    with open (write_file, 'w') as file1:
        file1.write(str(data))
```

Comment: Do you want a seperate line for each item in the list data? In your context manager (with), do a for loop over the list and write a line for each item in the list.

Comment: You are opening 2 write_files, 1 in read and 1 in write mode. Is that a typo?

Comment: I made it that way as it initially reading the written file where the dropbox metadata was writen. Can incorporate all into one block now :)

Comment: I don't think that is good practice. Even surprised that it works. It may cause bugs, so it may be better to name your files differently.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will incorporate moving forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want a newline for every part that was split by the `'FileMetadata'` string.

Instead of your `file1.write(str(data))`, did you try `file1.write("\n".join(data))`?

Comment: Bingo. The beauty here is this is the ultimate way of comma-separating lists of strings